# Simulating TCP Client Traffic using Ncat

Tags: bash, tcp, netcat

I am attempting to make a simple script that would simulate a TCP client that periodically initiates a connection with an echo server and generates a random string to send to the server, which it then should send back to the client. Below is the simple bash script I have set up:

```
while :
do
        var="$(shuf -i 9-19 -n 1)" # generate a random number between 9-19
        rand="$(pwgen "$var" 1)" # generate a random string of size var
        echo "$rand" | nc localhost 1234 
        sleep 5
done
```

The server itself is just the simple command ran in the terminal:

`ncat -l 1234 -k --exec "/bin/cat"`

I'm noticing in Wireshark for scenario 1, that the TCP 3 way handshake completes fine, the client sends the data seemingly fine, but then I don't ever see the response, or echo, from the server. It seems that the server is still able to respond to the client closing the connection. The capture for the first scenario is [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5tUq.png)

This is contrast to scenario two if I had just run `nc localhost 1234` in a terminal and began typing things. In this scenario, I can see in Wireshark that the server responds as expected, with the response occurring in [line 6 here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUw3G.png)

Why is it that I cannot see the response in case 1 as I do in case 2? How would I need to change my script to reflect this intended behavior (if it is possible)? Finally, in scenario 2, why does the server respond back to the client twice, first with a [ACK] with no data but then another [PSH,ACK] immediately after containing the "echo" data (as seen in lines 5 and 6 of the second capture)?

**EDIT:**  After browsing around some more, I think I have found the solution to the issue. This is due to netcat exiting before a response can be received as detailed by https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289364/netcat-doesnt-print-response. Thus a simple fix would be to change the script such that it uses the `-q` delay option.

```
 while :
    do
            var="$(shuf -i 9-19 -n 1)" 
            rand="$(pwgen "$var" 1)" 
            echo "$rand" | nc -q 1 localhost 1234 #change here
            sleep 5
    done
```

I am still unsure to the third question I had, but have suspicions that this may be the synchronization of the new window size of the connection? Thank you again for any insights.

Comment: Maybe that would be an alternative: `echo "$rand" >/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/1234`